# SQL Server 2005 SSIS Issuse with Debugging and Saving Script Tasks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, ssis

Last week I had an interesting issue arise when I was building a new SSIS package with a script task. At one point in the process of building and debugging the debugger suddenly stop hitting my break points. At the time I thought maybe the debugger got hung up or something weird like that. So I did a restart on the server and re-opened SSIS.

When I opened up my package that I had been working on for the last few days, and then opened the script task. the script task was empty (had the default code you get when you create a new script task) lost all my work. I started building it again as I had a really good idea on what I had already built. I rebuilt a few functions and tried to debug, it would not hit any break points still. Saved my current progress and rebooted again.

After the reboot I opened up my script task, again lost all my work. At this point I am unable to get SSIS to save any script task and I am unable to debug any script task code, including already built packages. I have scoured the net looking for an answer and have found no clue as to what is going on. HELP!

Prior to this happening, I had no issues debugging or saving packages. I have already reinstalled SSIS once and still does the same thing...

Comment: As just a wild, off-the-wall suggestion, have you checked for a virus?

Comment: Yes, we have Nod32 running on the machine